# Pi appears very small with newtxmath scaling

Tags: pdftex, newtxmath

Generally i dont like the symbol `pi` given in the newpxmath package. So i tried to use the cmroman pi using the following command. But then due pi appears too small since i scale the text and math. Any idea how to scale the `pi` symbol??

```
   \documentclass[12pt]{article}
   \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
     \usepackage[scaled=1.2]{newtxtext}
      \usepackage[scaled=1.2,cmbraces,varbb]{newpxmath}

   \DeclareSymbolFont{lettersCM}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
    \SetSymbolFont{lettersCM}{bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
      \let\txpi\pi
    \DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{lettersCM}{"19}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
    Pie appears very small
   $$\frac{k\pi}{12} = \frac{22}{7}$$
     \end{flushleft}
    \end{document}
```

and the output appears like this[image]

Comment: Why are you scaling the fonts? Use `extarticle` if you want 14pt size. I'm also dubious about the combination of `newtxtext` and `newpxmath`.

Comment: @egreg Yeah that would be a good option. But can't i scale the pi symbol? Just curious :)

Comment: @egreg 14pt becomes too big actually. I generally like to scale a little bit. As for the other question "the math of newpx appear much better and clearer than the math of the newtx".

Comment: @If you have 12pt main size and scale the fonts by 1.2, you get 14.4pt, don't you? As for the other part, the letters in `newpxfonts` are completely different from and incompatible with the letters in `newtxtext`.

Comment: @egreg: I dont know how 1.2 works, but i can assure u that 14pt in extarticle looks far bigger than how the scaling 1.2 looks. Anyway, If there is a way to scale please do let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't scale the fonts. Your main font size is 14pt (precisely 14.4pt) and it's much better, if you really want such humongous size, to use a proper package/class like `extarticle`.

For the comparison below I used your exact code, just adding a `lipsum` paragraph. The `extarticle` version is

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[cmbraces,varbb]{newpxmath}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareSymbolFont{lettersCM}{OML}{cmm} {m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{lettersCM}{bold}{OML}{cmm} {b}{it}
\let\txpi\pi
\DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{lettersCM}{"19}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushleft}
Pie appears very small
\[\frac{k\pi}{12} = \frac{22}{7}\]
\end{flushleft}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I left `flushleft`, although it doesn't appear necessary. I changed `$$...$$` into the proper `\[...\]`.

Here's the comparison. You will see that the pi is correctly sized and also the lines are well spaced.

The font size is the same in both versions, which have been scaled by the same amount.

[image]

Some more information. If I add a command for showing the font used in the document, I get

```
\T1/ntxtlf/m/n/12=select font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 14.39996pt
```

for your version with scaling and

```
\T1/ntxtlf/m/n/14.4=select font ntx-Regular-tlf-t1 at 14.4pt
```

for my version with `extarticle`. The difference in the fifth decimal is surely not relevant.

***Caveat*** Don't mix `newtxtext` with `newpxmath`: the letters are very different and visually incompatible with each other.